# Assert\Type not working in Symfony2 form validation

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a form containing a field that expects an integer. This is the field definition in the form type entity definition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer", message="Number of pieces must be a number.")
 * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual(value=1, message="Number of pieces cannot be lower than 1.")
 */
protected $numberOfPiecesSent;
```

The relevant form builder looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('numberOfPiecesSent', 'integer', array('label' => 'Number of pieces sent:', 'required' => false));
}
```

When I submit the form with a non-numerical value in the field (say, 'aaa'), it just saves the form and leaves the field numberOfPiecesSent NULL in the database instead of failing on validation. I also tried to make the field non-NULL, but that didn't help. Any ideas why this isn't working, please?

Comment: You can try [regex](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)

Comment: Surprisingly not even the Regex works. This is very strange because the GreaterThanOrEqual() assert works, so in general, my asserts do work.

Comment: Checkout the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested and this works fine. You can add constraints into your property below. You can remove NotBlank as well. Modify as you wish.

entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $numberOfPiecesSent;
```

form

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Range;

->add(
    'numberOfPiecesSent',
    'integer',
    [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(
                [
                    'message' => 'The numberOfPiecesSent is required.'
                ]
            ),
            new Range(
                [
                    'min' => 1,
                    'minMessage' => "The numberOfPiecesSent must contain at least {{ limit }}"
                ]
            )
        ]
    ]
)
```

---

UPDATE

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

->add(
    'name',
    'text',
    [
        'constraints' => [
            new Regex(
                [
                    'pattern' => "/^[0-9]+$/"
                ]
            )
        ]
    ]
)
```

OR

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

->add(
    'name',
    'integer',
    [
        'constraints' => [
            new Regex(
                [
                    'pattern' => "/^[0-9]+$/"
                ]
            )
        ]
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this. It only works if I use the NotBlank constraint, which I don't want to use because I need the field to be optional, so this workaround isn't a solution for me. I am really wondering why the Assert\Type thing doesn't work. I might end up writing my own validator, but I'd prefer to use built-in features.

Comment: Thank you. So this actually works for you? I just tried this and it doesn't do anything. When I submit 'aaa' as the value of the field, it just saves is as NULL. The field also has `'required' => false` set on it. I am on Symfony 2.7.

Comment: Aah, it works with the widget type set to 'text' instead of 'integer'. Makes sense. I wish it worked with the Assert\Type solution. I am glad this works. I am going to upvote this because this is a good workaround, but I'll wait a few days before accepting it in case someone knows how to get the Assert\Type working, which is the subject of the original question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: That's fine. Glad that it provides some sort of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make field not null with:
`@ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)`
or did you also tried with the assert NotNull ?
http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html

Comment: I tried `@ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)` - that didn't help. I didn't try the NotNull thing because I actually need the field to be optional. I just need ensure that if any value is entered in it, it has to be a number.

Comment: Peut-on voir ton controller également ?